# Sum of the reciprocal of tetration?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, tetration

Let $$f(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{{}^xn}$$ where ${}^xn$ is n tetrated to the xth.
What are f(2) and f(3), and could you please also explain how you reached these answers?

Comment: @Arashium tetration is repeated exponentiation, i.e. ${}^2x = x^x$, ${}^3x = x^{x^x}$

Comment: I would simply sum the first 10 to 20 terms and arrive at an approximation for f(2) with error smaller 1/10^10 (which has ten digits in the denominator) or 1/20^20 and for f(3) this goes even faster.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I've seen an exact value for f(2)  somewhere.

Comment: Nothing with elementary functions using http://oeis.org/A073009 Only an integral. But an integral means nothing more than a sum, I think.

Comment: Google with 1.291285997 gives a lot of discussion, but no closed form seems to be known.