# Series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ ^{s}n}$ where $^{s}n$ is the tetration of $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, tetration

I am interested in the function $$T(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ ^{s}n}$$ where $s$ is an integer and $ ^s n$ is $n^{n^{n^{...}}}$ $s$ times. I know these series are convergent since tetration of $n>1$ results in incredibly large values. I am also familiar with the Sophomore's Dream Identity $$\int_{0}^1 x^{-x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}=T(2)$$ and $T(1)$ is the harmonic series.

My question is does $T(s)$ have an integral representation for other values of $s$? And if not, are there other identities related to this function?

Comment: For s=0, the sum diverges, since $\frac{1}{^0 n}=1$.
For s=1, the sum also diverges since $\frac{1}{^1 n}=\frac{1}{n}$.
For non integer values of s, we would of course need a definition of tetration to non-integrer values and/or complex values.  Presumably we would use Kneser's Tetration.  If we used Kneser, then possibly for s>1 the series would converge.  And then T(2) =  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^n}$, the Sophmore's Dream.

Comment: @SheldonL I see, but wouldn't the series converge for for $s>2$ because if you compare the partial sums to those of the Sophomore's Dream Identity proven by Bernoulli, they are smaller.

Comment: Correct, but the Sophmore's dream is for T(2).

Comment: I've a vague idea that this a duplicate, didn't find the older version yet...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695071/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-tetration It never got a proper response though. Probably because there is not much that has been done about that kind of series.